# Prevent control go ahead with form-inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `form-inline` class that put all the controls on the same line, but I noticed that when I resize the window the button near the textbox go to the next line. I want to prevent this. Take a look at the image:

[image]

[image]

and this is the code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 hideable-sidebar">
      <div class="well">
        <span><b>Resources</b></span>
        <form class="form-inline">
          <input type="text" placeholder="type text here"
                 class="form-control" id="resource_filter" />
          <button class="clear btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button"
                  title="clean">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></span>
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you resize, your window becomes smaller, but your text box doesn't. So when the window isn't wide enough to hold both the text box and the button, the button gets pushed to the next line. To prevent this you should dynamically adjust the size of the text box too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the `Bootstrap` [Button Addons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons) under input groups. This way it will stay proportional during a window resize. Be sure that your input and button are using the same size:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 hideable-sidebar">
      <div class="well">
        <span><b>Resources</b></span>
        <form class="form-inline">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="type text here" class="form-control" id="resource_filter" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="clear btn btn-default" type="button" title="clean">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></span>
              </button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I'll use this.